# Is there a way to return data and refresh the page with a server action and Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to create a webapp with Next.js (13.4.9) and I would use the server action. With the server action, I would send data to my action, this action is going to treat this data and return me a string. The only way I've found so far to get the result data from the action is with the cookies. So is there an other way (easier) I can get the data from the server action ? And I would  also refresh the page or redirect the user to an other page just after the server action (like with php). So how can I do a refreshing or a redirect after the server action ?

Here is my actual code :

```js
// page.tsx

"use client";
import React, { useTransition, useState } from "react";
import { SendTicket } from "@/actions/TicketAction";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

export default function TicketPage(){

    const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
    const [ name, setName ] = useState<string>("");
    const [ age, setAge ] = useState<number>(0);

    

    return(
        <main>
                <form action={() => startTransition(() => SendTicket({
                    name: name, age: age
                }))}>
                    <input type="text" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Your name" />
                    <input type="number" value={age} onChange={(e) => setAge(parseInt(e.target.value))}
                    placeholder="Your age" />
                    <button type="submit">
                        Valider
                    </button>
                </form>
                { isPending ? <span>Loading...</span> : <></> }
                <Result />
        </main>
    )
}

function Result(){
    const ResultString = Cookies.get("ResultString");
    Cookies.remove("ResultString");

    return(
        <p>{ResultString?.toString()}</p>
    )
}
```

```js
// TicketAction.ts

"use server";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export interface TicketInformationProps {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

export async function SendTicket(TicketInforamtion: TicketInformationProps){
    console.log(`[NEW TICKET]`);
    console.log(`Nom: ${TicketInforamtion.name}`);
    console.log(`Age: ${TicketInforamtion.age.toString()}`);
    console.log(`\n\n\n`);

    const result = `You are ${TicketInforamtion.name} and you are ${TicketInforamtion.age.toString()} yo.`;
    cookies().set({
        name: "ResultString",
        value: result,
        path: "/ticket",
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 1),
        secure: true,

    });
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath) answer your question?

Comment: @FabioNettis I have just been trying but it doesn't seem working with the server actions. It doesn't redirect the user on the other path.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the return data as follows:

```
import { experimental_useFormState as useFormState } from 'react-dom'
```

...

```
  const [state, formAction] = useFormState(action);
```

...

Where state will be undefined (or optionally set to an initial value) until a return value is received from the server action

Answer (score 0):

For Next.js v.14:

You have to use `useFormState()` hook and after mutating the data in your action server and return an object which will cause the component that sent the form data to rerender (it's like a refresh).

Note: You have to use `revalidatePath('/')` after mutating the data to tell Next.js that the component that sent the form data is a dynamic page so it will re-render on new requests (when it will re-render because of useFormState hook) instead of serving a cached version of the page.

Answer (score -1):

server actions are still experimental. you should have this setup in `next.config.js`

```
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    serverActions: true,
  },
};
```

"use server" directive should be placed at the top of the component function body.

```
// this will refresh 
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";

export async function SendTicket(TicketInforamtion: TicketInformationProps){   

    const result = `You are ${TicketInforamtion.name} and you are ${TicketInforamtion.age.toString()} yo.`;
    "use server"
    cookies().set({
        name: "ResultString",
        value: result,
        path: "/ticket",
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 1),
        secure: true,
    });
    revalidatePath("/route");

}
```

server actions are used to mutate data on the server or do server specific tasks. I do not think that you can have a return value and use it inside the component